# Loading never stops on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support

I recently observed that the website loading never stops when I use the site. As a result, I am not able to post answers and comments.
[image]

Refer the image. The loading sign (rotating circle can be seen on the left top corner).

Why is this happening?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try disabling all your plugins? This kind of behaviour could be an indication of malicious scripts being loaded. Try running some virus / malware scanners, as well.

Comment: This happens only on SO and especially when I click to open a particular question. And I have not installed any plugins recently. I have avast which makes sure that I browse safe. Do you still think it's a malware targetting only SO?

Comment: That actually would be a good thing to check. Try it in Firefox and see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: @BSMP It's working properly on firefox. But I have been using chrome to access SO and this problem has occured recently.

Comment: Unable to duplicate with Chrome 49.0.2623.112 m on Windows 7. It's updating now though; I'll check with the new version. EDIT: Can't duplicate it in version 50.0.2661.87 m either.

Comment: *I have not installed any plugins recently.* - Have you updated any of them recently?

Comment: Plugins get updated automatically on the reg.  Could easily be a bugged plugin.

Comment: I am running a malwarebytes scan. It has already detected 38 objects. I don't understand why avast is unable to detect these stuffs. I'll just repair the system and check if it works.

Comment: @BSMP the only active plugins are adblocker which is disabled on SO and avast safe search plugin. I also have a php console plugin active. I updated avast recently.

Comment: What is a malware object of type `key`? It was detected by malwarebytes. IS it a keylogger?

Comment: @MathewsMathai I presume a registry key? See [what does it mean for MalwareBytes to find malicious registry keys but nothing else?](http://superuser.com/q/402487)

Comment: Thanks for that @DavidPostill

Comment: @MathewsMathai Chrome sometimes just keeps refreshing/loading even when you don't have malware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by following a couple of steps:

- Did a malwarebytes scan which detected and removed 92 PUPs from my system (Avast didn't detect these though). This didn't solve my issue though.
- I reset the settings for Google Chrome and reactivated the plugins. This solved my issue.

Summing up: Malwarebytes + settings reset (for Chrome) solved the issue.

Comment: lol, I know it was Chrome before opening the question:)

Comment: But this was so unsual @MartinJames

Comment: If, while putting your settings back, you run across the one that caused the problem it may be useful to update your answer. It looks like there's at least one other person who's encountered this issue.

Comment: @BSMP I did a complete settings reset. I believe that it was some kind of bug or PUP which might have got installed (avast missed it probably). So I have no idea about what particular setting reset reversed the effect. I tried some individual reset like plugin deactivation etc. but it didn't work so I went for the complete reset. It could have been a problem with the cookies too because this loading error occured only with SO (when a particular question was opened). It was surprising that meta SO worked perfectly.

Comment: @MartinJames: Chrome wasn't really the issue. If the OP had been using FireFox, he'd probably gotten the same malware & issues.

Comment: @Cerbrus SO worked perfect with Firefox. Even in case of chrome, this particular malware/issue targetted only SO. That's the main point of concern. Why not other sites or pages?

`Even in SO, the problem did not occur with meta.`

Comment: You could've picked up the malware with Chrome. If you had been using FF at _that_ specific moment, the issue might've been the other way around. I'm just saying that that anti-chrome bias is nonsense. Apparently the malware was designed to specifically target SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes. I support you in that. It was definitely not an issue with chrome. I used chrome to access SO from the very beginning I joined this community and this issue is recent. The important part is `Apparently the malware was designed to specifically target SO`. Something has to be done about this.

Comment: *I did a complete settings reset.* - I understand, I was just suggesting that you might, in normal use of the browser, change some of the settings back to what they were before the reset and if you do you might figure out what exactly went wrong. If you don't, that's fine.

Comment: I think the Community user just poked this post because it's technically unanswered. You may want to accept your answer.